# Reusable admin form generator always checks last field

Tags: django, django-admin

(This is all pseudocode and is not guaranteed to run.)

I am trying to make a "django admin form generator function" that outputs a django form. The current use case is to write reusable code that disallows admins from leaving a field empty, without also [marking these fields as non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689804/django-tests-for-zero-downtime-schema-migrations).

So suppose there exists a model `Foo`, in which are some nullable fields:

```
class Foo(Model):
    field1 = FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    field2 = FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    field3 = FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
```

and corresponding `FooAdmin` and `FooForm`, such that these fields cannot be made `None` from the admin.

```
class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    class FooForm(ModelForm):

        class Meta(object):
            model = Foo
            fields = '__all__'

        def _ensure_no_blanks(self, field):
            value = self.cleaned_data.get(field)
            if value is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('This field is required.'))
            return value

        # repeat methods for every field to check
        def clean_field1(self):
            return self._ensure_no_blanks('field1')

        def clean_field2(self):
            return self._ensure_no_blanks('field2')

        def clean_field3(self):
            return self._ensure_no_blanks('field3')

    form = FooForm
```

As you can see, having to write `clean_field1`, `clean_field2`, and `clean_field_n` are repetitive and error-prone, so I write this helper function to generate model admins:

```
import functools
from django import forms

def form_with_fields(model_class, required_fields):

    class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta(object):
            model = model_class
            fields = '__all__'

        def ensure_no_blanks(self, field):
            print field
            value = self.cleaned_data.get(field)
            if value is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required.')
            return value

    # make a clean_bar method for every field that I need to check for None
    for field_name in required_fields:
        handler = functools.partial(CustomForm.ensure_no_blanks, field=field_name)
        setattr(CustomForm, 'clean_' + field_name, lambda self: handler(self))

    return CustomForm

class CustomAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = form_with_fields(Foo, ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])
```

However, if you run such an admin, and if you do try to save the `Foo` model through the admin, you will see `print field` printing `field3` three times in the terminal (i.e. all `partial`s are retaining the last-run value).

Other attempts include overriding `CustomForm`'s `__getattr__()`, and wrapping `CustomForm` in a `type('Form', (CustomForm,), ...`, which also exhibit the same behavior.

Is there a dry way to achieve this?

Comment: I think it would be much simpler to do that validation in the `clean` method and add the errors to the corresponding fields with [`add_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error). You could also make the fields `blank = False`, if it's just an on/off global operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setattr(CustomForm, 'clean_' + field_name, lambda self: handler(self))
```

The problem is the lambda function. The `handler` is defined outside of the lambda. It is accessed when the lambda is called, not when it is defined. Since this is after the for-loop has completed, you always get the function that uses the last field name.

See [this FAQ entry](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) from the Python docs for a fuller explanation.

In this case, you don't need a lambda at all. Just use `handler` itself.

```
setattr(CustomForm, 'clean_' + field_name, handler)
```

However, as Paulo suggests in the comment, it would be much

```
def clean(self):
    for field in required_fields(self):
        self.ensure_no_blanks(field)
```

You may need to change `ensure_no_blanks` to use `add_error` so that the validation errors are added to the correct field.

```
if value is None:
    self.add_error(field, 'This field is required.')
```

Another option would be to set the `required=True` for the fields in the `__init__` method, then let the form take care of validation.

```
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = model_class
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in required_fields:
            self.fields[field].required = True
```

Comment: I think I like the last one the most. Thanks!